# Why the 1st parameter in the Call statement is not surrounded with % sign? (Batch File)

Tags: variables, batch-file, function-call

**How this batch file still works when the 1st parameter in the call statement is not surrounded with '%' sign?**

### How 'Number1' variable still gets the value 1 ?

```
@echo off

set "fst=0"
set "fib=1"
set "limit=1000000000"
```

> **call:myFibo fib,%fst%,%limit%**

```
echo.The next Fibonacci number greater or equal %limit% is %fib%.

echo.&pause&goto:eof


::--------------------------------------------------------
::-- Function section starts below here
::--------------------------------------------------------

:myFibo  -- calculate recursively the next Fibonacci number greater or equal to a limit
::       -- %~1: return variable reference and current Fibonacci number
::       -- %~2: previous value
::       -- %~3: limit
SETLOCAL
set /a "Number1=%~1"
set /a "Number2=%~2"
set /a "Limit=%~3"
set /a "NumberN=Number1 + Number2"
```

> if /i %NumberN% LSS %Limit% **call:myFibo NumberN,%Number1%,%Limit%**

```
(ENDLOCAL
    IF "%~1" NEQ "" SET "%~1=%NumberN%"
)
goto:eof
```

Answer (score 1):

Parameters passed to bat file or subroutine are accessed with %1,%2..%9.
For more info - [arguments](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) ; [shift](http://ss64.com/nt/shift.html)

And `SET /A` does not need %-enclosement to calculate variables value.

So in your case Number1 gets the value of the first argument , Number2 the second  and numberN the sum of both.Number1 is set to fib  which is later expanded to its variable value by `SET /A`

Comment: I just ran it again, when giving the '%' sign around the first parameter i.e. 'fib' it gives the output : "The next Fibonacci number greater or equal 1000000000 is 1."
However removing the '%' sign from the 2nd and 3rd parameters gives the right answer : "The next Fibonacci number greater or equal 1000000000 is 1134903170."
WHY SO...???

Comment: In any case the 1st parameter 'fib' should not be enclosed with '%' sign, then only the right answer comes, irrespective of the enclosure of 2nd and 3rd parameters.

Comment: if it's enclosed with % this condition will fail : `IF "%~1" NEQ "" SET "%~1=%NumberN%"`